# How populate prototype cell text labels with NSDictionary object populated with JSON data using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary, nstableview, afnetworking

New to iOS.  I am downloading JSON data using AFNetworking and putting the data in a Dictionary object.  This is done in the following code:

```
-(void)locationRequest
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sitespec/php/getlocations.php"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//AFNetworking asynchronous url request
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                     JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse         *response, id responseObject)
                                     {

                                         self.locationsFromJSON = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

                                         NSLog(@"JSON RESULT %@", responseObject);
                                         NSLog(@"JSON DICTIONARY %@", _locationsFromJSON);
                                         [self.tableView reloadData];
                                     }
                                     failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id responseObject)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                     }];

[operation start];

}
```

I am getting the data and populating the Dictionary array as seen in the outpur of the NSLOG calls below:

```
2013-05-12 12:44:08.851 sitespec[2024:c07] JSON RESULT (
    {
    city = "Rocky Mount";
    id = 1;
    name = "Rocky Mount";
    phone = "(252) 451-1811";
    state = NC;
    "street_address" = "620 Health Drive";
    zip = 27804;
},
    {
    city = "Elizabeth City";
    id = 2;
    name = "Elizabeth City";
    phone = "(252) 335-4355";
    state = NC;
    "street_address" = "109 Corporate Drive";
    zip = 27906;
}
)
2013-05-12 12:44:08.852 sitespec[2024:c07] JSON DICTIONARY (
    {
    city = "Rocky Mount";
    id = 1;
    name = "Rocky Mount";
    phone = "(252) 451-1811";
    state = NC;
    "street_address" = "620 Health Drive";
    zip = 27804;
},
    {
    city = "Elizabeth City";
    id = 2;
    name = "Elizabeth City";
    phone = "(252) 335-4355";
    state = NC;
    "street_address" = "109 Corporate Drive";
    zip = 27906;
}
)
```

BUT, here is where I am lost.....

How do I access this data in the Dictionary object in my

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method?

SOmething like:

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = [self.locationsFromJSON objectForKey:@"name"];
```

???

This is not working and I get a SIGBART error.  I just cant figure out how to read the data out and populate the table view?

How do I do this?  ANy help is GREATLY appreciated.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this very often and I don't understand why people struggle to extract data from a dictionary and populate a table view with the content of a dictionary. I don't understand why people don't create model classes for the JSON response and after that add the models into an array depending on what they need.

So *Tommy* I strongly recommend that you create a class model named Address (for example) and add all the JSON attributes as properties to your model class, when you parse your JSON you create Address class instances that you will add to an array. After that, in your table view class you will have an array of addresses and for:

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` you will return `yourAddressesArray.count`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    Address *address = [yourAddressesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    //assign your address properties to labels etc
```

}

It's easier when you have model classes ;)

**EDIT FOR PARSING**

From what I see in your question you have an array of dictionaries. So I suggest to do something like this:

In your Address class create an imit method with josn:

```
-(id)initAddressWithJSON:(id)JSON {
    slef = [super init];
    if(self) {
      self.city = [JSON objectForKey:@"city"];
      // set all the properties here
    }
    return self;
}
```

When you received the json response called, let's say "jsonResopnse" you should do something like:

```
-(NSArray*)myAddressesFromJSON:(id)JSON {

   //you should add a validation here for JSON  (not null not empty)
   NSMutableArray *addresses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   Address *address;
   for(NSDictionary *addressDict in JSON) {
       address = [[Address alloc] initWithJSON:addressDict];
       [addresses addObject:address]; 
   }
   return addresses;
}
```

Note, I wrote the code from my head and I didn't used Xcode :) and is possible that there are some  build errors (misspelling), but I hope you got the idea. Also I suppose you are using JSONKit.

Comment: I created an Address model and added all the attributes of my JSON data. I have imported the Address.h file into my tableView.m file where I download the data and wish to show the tableView.  I have an Array defined called locationsFromJSON to do as you instruct above.  A follow on question though, you say " when you parse your JSON you create Address class instances that you will add to an array"  I have the JSON response in the returned value: responseObject.  How do I create the Address class instances and add them to the array?

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you use the JSON request and the `UITableView` in same class. Set a breakpoint in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methode and check what if there are already Data. if no, then:

ask in the `- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` methode or already in `numberOfSections` if your dictionary is already filled. else return 0.

And in the methode where you receive the JSON data call a `[tableView reloadData];`

if that is not the problem, please tell where you get the SIGBART error ;)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to danypata for the great feedback.  I took a slightly different route to get this going.  What got me thinking was danypata's comment "looks like you have a array of dictionaires in your JSON response"....  In the AFNetworking block were I get the JSON response, I assign the JSON object to an array defined as a property in the current TableVIewCOntroller.

```
-(void)locationRequest
```

{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"];

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//AFNetworking asynchronous url request
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                     JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject)
                                     {

                                         self.locationsFromJSON = responseObject;
                                         [self.tableView reloadData];
                                     }
                                     failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id responseObject)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                     }];

[operation start];

}
```

I also declare a Mutable Dictionary property and a NSString property for each value in my JSON response. In the TableVIewCell method below, I grab the dictionary objected located at index.row and read out the values for the keys and assign them to the prototype cell label properties.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"locCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}


self.dictObj = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.dictObj = [_locationsFromJSON objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text =  [_dictObj valueForKey:@"city"];  
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_dictObj valueForKey:@"phone"];     
return cell;
}
```

THis worked!  It just took someone else pointing out the obvious "looks like you have an Array of Dictionary objects....."